# Let $H\triangleleft G$ and $K\triangleleft G$ show that $H\cap K\triangleleft G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

Please check my proof

If $H\triangleleft G$ then $gHg^{-1}=H $ for every $g\in G $

If $K\triangleleft G$ then $gKg^{-1}=K$ for every $g\in G$

Then $H\cap K = gHg^{-1}gKg^{-1}=gHKg^{-1}$

Then $H\cap K\triangleleft G$

Comment: Can you explain your sets and the meaning of your notations? Also what do you mean by "If $H\triangleleft G$ then $gHg^{-1}$"?

Comment: I edited it yet ,but I think my proof my wrong now -  -

Comment: Well, I suggest you have to do extra research. Say for instance, you can go this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl1Ep9M_dWA I think this link explain the proof clearly.---:)

Comment: @juniven thank  ^ ^

Comment: Why $H\cap K=gHg^{-1}gKg^{-1}$? Shouldn't it be $H\cap K=gHg^{-1}\cap gKg^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line is wrong: you seem to be claiming that $H\cap K=HK$, which isn't true (e.g. try $G=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, $H=\langle2\rangle$, $K=\langle3\rangle$).

What you should be doing is proving that $g(H\cap K)g^{-1}=H\cap K$. Hint: Take $a\in H\cap K$; then $a\in H$ and $a\in K$, so what can you say about $gag^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

You proof is flawed as
$$H\cap K \subseteq H\subseteq HK$$
where equality does not need to hold so you cannot say that.

A better method is this to show that for $x\in H\cap K$ we have $gxg^{-1}\in H\cap K$ for all $g$.

This is trivial as $x\in H$ gives that $gxg^{-1}\in H$ and $x\in K$ gives that $gxg^{-1}\in K$ which means that $gxg^{-1}\in H\cap K$.